# TinyMCE loads in GWT, but toolbar buttons does not work

Tags: gwt, button, tinymce, toolbar, smartgwt

I'm using [tinymce-gwt](http://code.google.com/p/tinymce-gwt/) in a smartgwt project. I've written some code to create a panel & add a textarea item to that panel & then load tinymce editor. It works fine & I can load it correctly & it shows all desired buttons well. But I've a problem that non of toolbar buttons work (nothing happen by clicking on them). This is the native GWT method I've used to initialize TinyMCE:

```
protected native void init(String id) /*-{
    try{
        $wnd.tinyMCE.init({
                mode: "exact",
                elements: id,
                theme : "advanced",
                theme_advanced_buttons1 : "fontselect,fontsizeselect,formatselect,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,separator,sub,sup,separator,cut,copy,paste,undo,redo",
                theme_advanced_buttons2 : "justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,separator,numlist,bullist,outdent,indent,separator,forecolor,backcolor,separator,hr,link,unlink,jbimages,image,table,separator,asciimath,asciimathcharmap,asciisvg",//media, code
                theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
                theme_advanced_fonts : "Arial=arial,helvetica,sans-serif,Courier New=courier new,courier,monospace,Georgia=georgia,times new roman,times,serif,Tahoma=tahoma,arial,helvetica,sans-serif,Times=times new roman,times,serif,Verdana=verdana,arial,helvetica,sans-serif",
                theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
                theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
                theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
                relative_urls : false,
                plugins : 'jbimages,asciimath,asciisvg,table,inlinepopups,media',
                AScgiloc : '/tinyMCE/plugins/asciisvg/php/svgimg.php',
                ASdloc : 'plugins/asciisvg/js/d.svg',   
                content_css : "css/content.css"
            });
    }catch(e){
        alert(e);
    }
}-*/;
```

Comment: any errors ? or maybe some relevant log informations ?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to see this two other projects that seem to do what you are trying.

http://code.google.com/p/gwt-html-editor/source/browse/branches/gwt1.4/src/com/gc/gwt/wysiwyg/client/tinymce/TinyMCE.java?r=89

or this:

http://code.google.com/p/tinymce-gwt/source/browse/trunk/tinymce-gwt/tinymceGwt/src/gr/open/client/TinyMCE.java